# How to put the name of the file in directory I'm at to command?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am new to GNU/Linux and I am wondering how to get the contents of a directory I am at now to command. I have a long file name and I want to make it executable by "chmod", can I do it somehow without typing the whole file name after chmod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time tab-completion in the shell should be good enough. If you press the `tab`-key after having typed part of the filename, any shell with autocompletion will try to complete the filename. How exactly that works depends on the shell you use (by default this is `bash` on ubuntu). Different shells have different autocompletions, and some allow further configuration (see e.g. [this page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html) for zsh).

If you are on an unknown system, you can do

```
echo $SHELL
```

to figure out which shell you are in (this is set by [`login(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/login)). You can do `chsh -l` to see the available shells, too.

For executables the shell will autocomplete names found in the directories listed in `$PATH`. If you want to execute a local file, you need to do `./myprog`, put `myprog` or a symlink to it into one of the directories, or - not recommended, unless you know what you do - put the directory of the executable into `$PATH`.

For doing more complex things on multiple files, look at [`find(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

In general, you might want to look for answers to these questions over at the [Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Now when I want to execute file I and I start typing it, tab doesn't autocomplete it

Comment: Pulled up comment into answer, since it has immediate relevance

Answer (score 0):

Type the first part of the filename and press tab to autocomplete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

first **cd** to the directory you want to get the contents and use **ls** see the contents of it, type one or two letters of the filename and use tab. You need permissions to use **chmod**.